# Using AVRDude to program AtTiny via Arduino-as-ISP

Tags: arduino, avr, avrdude

As I understand, I can use Arduino as ISP. Most instructions start with "load ArduinoISP from examples".

But then I want to load existing `.hex` file to the target chip. E.g.

```
AvrDude -> ArduinoBoard+ArduinoISP -> targetChip
```

And I fail miserably to find proper instructions though I believe this is possible and perhaps even already explained somewhere. I could not find instruction mainly because keywords yield instructions on many related but different topics.

I suspect that as Arduino uses avrdude I can sneak how it works when programming via ArduinoISP... At least I'm trying in this direction right now, but I would be glad if someone can help me to save the time.

**UPD** I've succeeded with the help of the answer below. The last thing to mention - I hate arduino's instruction for giving an image instead of specifying wiring. As I understand it is like:

- pin 10 to reset
- pin 11 to mosi
- pin 12 to miso
- pin 13 to sck

Comment: Google finds three sets of instructions very quickly.

Comment: Would you care to share at least exact search query for poor person who are not as smart as you?

Comment: http://git.linformatronics.nl/gitweb/?p=makefile;a=summary

Comment: As I said it yields results to zounds of instructions on how to program target chip via ArduinoISP using Arduino IDE, writing separate sketch etc. I'm about something different, or am I wrong?

Comment: let me Google that for you comments run afoul of the be nice policy, please don't use them. Better to provide a link an answer or nothing at all thanks

Comment: For reference, in the Arduino IDE's [preferences.txt file](https://docs.arduino.cc/hacking/software/Preferences), change `build.verbose` and `upload.verbose` to `true` to cause the IDE to print out what commands it's using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you already have a binary file for flashing, [this page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) may help you. All you need to do is:

1. Connect the Arduino with loaded ArduinoISP sketch to the target chip
2. Run AVRDude. Make sure to specify a programmer type. Also note that ArduinoISP will work at lower serial speeds. Example:

   ```
   avrdude -p m328p -P /dev/ttyACM0 -c avrisp -b 19200 -U flash:w:release.hex
   ```

Comment: Oh yes, **this line** looks like exactly what I was searching for. I'll check it in a few minutes! I have no idea I should simply use "-c avrisp" for that case... Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, definitely works. Sorry for delay I've kicked about setting proper port, chip and path to config file. Thanks once more!